# extending an object of a basic class to an object of a complex class

Tags: c++, oop

how can I do that? I thought of an method in the complex class which copies every variable of the basic object to the complex object, but that seems a little bit to inconvenient.

```
class Basic
{
  //basic stuff
}

class Complex : public Basic
{
  //more stuff
}

Basic * basicObject = new Basic();
//now "extending" basicObject and "cast" it to Complex type
//which means copy everything in basicObject to an complexObject
```

or something like:

```
Complex * complexObject = new Complex();
complexObject.getEverythingFrom(basicObject);
```

seems to be too inconvenient, because everytime I change the Basic class, I have to change this "copy" method too.

Comment: I don't think what you're asking makes a lot of sense. Perhaps better to state your goals and not what you decided to be the first step.

Comment: You should probably read up a little more in inheritance and how it works.

Comment: You can't do this. When you create a `Basic` object you can't cast to derived `Complex`. Besides, every derived class manteins base class variables as their own. Why do you need to execute this copy if you may have direct access to all bases variables?

Comment: I want to replace some parts of a framework. I get an basic object from that framework and want to extend that, without altering the frameworks code.

Comment: @ben, if the framework create real `Basic` objects you must change this framework to create derived `Complex` objects and, using virtual methods extends `Basic`functionallity

Comment: @TioPepe can't do that for compatibility reasons, so I need to find another way or writing my "copy" method, which does the job, but I thought there would be an easier way with inheritance and pointer magic :)

Comment: @ben, so the below solution gave by Vite Falcon maybe the simplest way to extend `Basic` functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the values you want to share between the classes in protected section like so:

```
class Base
{
public:
int myPublicShared1;
int myPublicShared2;

Base& operator = (Base& other)
{
    // Copy contents in base across
    return *this;
}
protected:
int myShared1;
int myShared2;

private:
int notShared1;
int notShared2;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
Derived& operator = (Derived& other)
{
    Base::operator = (other);
    // copy the rest of variables specific to Derived class.
}
Derived& operator = (Base& other)
{
    Base::operator = (other);
}
// Derived now has all variables declared in Base's public and protected section
};
```

Comment: thanks. this seems quite good but unfortunately my Base class doesn't have an = operator but I will mark this as the solution, because it seems the most convenient solution.

Comment: @ben: I added the assignment operator to indicate that it has to be added. You could use `(*complexObject) = *baseObject`. Or you could even rename that function to be `Base::assign(const Base*)` and `Derived::assign(const Base*); Derived::assign(const Derived*)`.  Then you could use it like: `complexObject->assign(baseObject);` :).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, objects can not change their type.

So either you rewrite your program to right away create `Complex` objects, or you create a copy ctor so that you can do:

new Complex(*basicObject);

side note: from words like extend and the usage of new it seems you come from a java world. Don't make the mistake of thinking that how you do things in java is also how you do it in C++.

Comment: ok, that would be like my idea of a copy method, just in constructor, right?

Comment: @ben: a copy ctor is a fundamental element when working with objects in c++, you should maybe read about it a bit.